# Converting child class to parent

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two classes `Product` and `ExtendedProduct`. `ExtendedProduct` is derived from `Product` class. There are some more fields in `ExtendedProduct` class.

The problem is that when i cast `ExtendedProduct` into `Product` my `Product` object has the fields that `ExtendedProduct` has.

I just want to convert `ExtendedProduct` to `Product` class without any `ExtendedProduct` class' field appearing in `Product` class.

Comment: Map the properties of `ExtendedProduct` to a new instance of `Product`

Comment: Code will help to explain the phenomenon...

Comment: It's a violation of [polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)! The only way to do this is creating a constructor in `Product` class that accept an `ExtendedProduct` object as parameter.

Comment: Further reading: [Variance and Contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as your `ExtendedProduct` IS a `Product` casting it to the latter won´t change anything to the casted instance because you reference the same object. So after all you just look at the same object from another perspective.

In order to decouple your object from its base-type you´d need to create a clone, a completely new instance of `Product`, e.g. by using a copy-constructor:

```
class Product {
    public Product(Product p) {
        this.MyProp = p.MyProp;   
    }
}
```

Now you can call this like:

```
var product = new Product(myExtended);
```

Now both objects are completely unrelated, changing `MyProp` on one doesn´t affect the other (in fact it does, if `MyProp` is a reference-type, so you´d need a [deep clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net) instead).

However this sounds quite weird to me. Why would you want to "delete" the extended properties at all? You´ll need all the extra-information you provided earlier. You can simply cast to the parent-class which does not provide those properties at all:

```
var p = (Product) myExtendedProduct;
```

Now although `p` actually IS an instance of `ExtendedProduct` you can only access the properties from `Product`. This is a basic priciple of Polymorphism.

Comment: I guess OP will serialize the instance in the next step, that's why he doesn't want the unnecessary properties/fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could write an extension for the `ExtendedProduct` class and handle your mapping there:

```
public static Product ToProduct(this ExtendedProduct extProduct)
{
   var product = new Product();
   product.par1 = extProduct.Par1;
   // ...

   return product;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
var myExtProduct = new ExtendedProduct();
var product = myExtProduct.toProduct();
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly casting to the parent class will just change the way it is referred and not the structure. The below code snippet is something that you might find helpful. I am using JsonConvert for keeping it short. 
You can try to copy individual fields and generate a copy if you don't use Newtonsoft.

```
class ExtendedProduct : Product 
{
    object notrequired { get; set; }

    static Product copy(ExtendedProduct extendedProduct)
    {
        var orig = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(extendedProduct);
        Product copy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(orig);
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Just pass your ExtendedProduct object to the copy method which is static. You will get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want :

```
ExtendedProduct product = new ExtendedProduct();
Product p = product;
```

If you are not sure about conversion you can always do this :

```
ExtendedProduct product = new ExtendedProduct();
Product p = product as Product;
```

It is detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can also add a method to the base class that returns the base as the class of the base.

```
Public Class Base
{
    Public Base GetBase()
    {
        return (Base)this;
    }
}
```

Now if this base class is inherited.  You can call that method from it and get the Base class returned.

Comment: Where does this provide any value against simply doing `(Product) myExtended`?